# Debugging F# in Visual Studio Code -- projectPath

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, debugging, f#

I've successfully debugged F# projects in VS Code many times. I have the C# and Ionide extensions installed. I set up a basic F# console project and added the default ".NET: Launch C# project" launch configuration to `launch.json` via the "Add Configuration..." button. Now I'm used to specifying the program to debug via the `program` field, like so:

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net7.0/MyProject.dll"
```

But that field appears to have been deprecated in favour of `projectPath`, like so:

```
"projectPath": "${workspaceFolder}/MyProject.fsproj"
```

But upon F5, that yields the error:

```
Unable to determine debug settings for project 'c:/.../MyProject/MyProject.fsproj'
```

What else do I need to do to debug the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the configuration ".NET: Launch Executable file (console)" and just adjust the project file name for the "program" setting to point to your program dll as you have done above.

Also recommended:
`"preLaunchTask": "Build: MyProject.fsproj"`

I guess the "project" configuration is new and only available for C# so far.